# FilterInputStream doesn't execute

Tags: java, io

I'm trying to use FilterInputStream but I cannot make it work.
If I program a FilterReader all goes well:

```
import java.io.*;

class Filter extends FilterReader {
  Filter(Reader in) {
    super(in);
  }

  public int read() throws IOException {
    return 'A';
  }
}

public class TestFilter {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Reader in = new Filter(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println((char)in.read());
  }
}
```

execution is A

but if I use FiterInputStream, execution blocks reading:

```
import java.io.*;

class Filter extends FilterInputStream {
  Filter(InputStream in) {
    super(in);
  }

  public int read() throws IOException {
    return 'A';
  }
}

public class TestFilter {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Reader in = new InputStreamReader(new Filter(System.in));
    System.out.println((char)in.read());
  }
}
```

Comment: works for me! i executed the code (2nd one), pressed 's' + enter and it showed the same character in the console as well.

Answer (score 2):

In the first code, your Reader is:

```
new Filter(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

and its `read` method is the one you have overriden:

```
public int read() throws IOException {
    return 'A';
}
```

In the second code, your Reader is:

```
new InputStreamReader(new Filter(System.in));
```

and the `read` method of your Filter is not used. The Reader instead waits on `System.in` so you have to type in something (+ ENTER) to get something read.

Comment: As @user1496621 says InputStreamReader.read should delegate to Filter.read, but in fact it does delegate to Filter.read(byte[], int, int) which isn't overrriden

Answer (score 2):

In the first case in.read() directly invokes Filter.read() method.
In the second case in.read() invokes InputStreamReader.read(). 
 Now we might expect it to delegate the call to Filter.read(). But InputStreamReader.read() implementation does something else - I dont understand what it is doing. 
 But eventually **FilterInputStream.read(byte[], int, int)** method is invoked, which waits for the user input. So to get the behavior you expect - I guess - we need to override this read method - as shown below.

import java.io.*;

```
class Filter extends FilterInputStream {
  Filter(InputStream in) {
    super(in);
  }

  public int read() throws IOException {
    return 'A';
  }

  @Override
    public int read(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
      if(len == 0) {
          return 0;
      }
      b[off] = (byte) read();
      return 1;
     }

}

public class TestFilter {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Reader in = new InputStreamReader(new Filter(System.in));
    System.out.println((char)in.read());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your second `TestFilter` replace

```
Reader in = new InputStreamReader(new Filter(System.in));
```

With

```
InputStream in = new Filter(System.in);
```

This will execute `Filter.read()` on the class you created sending "A" to `System.out`.